# UIButton not showing up on iOS 5.1 iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

`UIBarButtonItem` not showing up on iOS 5.1 iPad 1, but works with iOS 6 on iPad 4.

```
_itemForImport = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:LS(@"Library", @"") style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(itemForImportTouched)];


+ (void) presentInPopoverFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item withSourceType:(NSString*)sourceType  {

    UIPopoverController* popover = [IPadFilesViewController getPopoverController];
    if (popover)
        return;

    IPadImagePickerController* pickerController = [[IPadImagePickerController alloc] initWithSourceType:sourceType];

    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pickerController];
    popover.delegate = pickerController;
    [IPadFilesViewController setPopoverController:popover];

    [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:item permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: why is the method `+presentInPopoverFromBarButtonItem:withSourceType:`  class method? are you using `ARC`? who keeps the `popover` alive beyond the scope?

Comment: LS(@"Library", @"")? Is that your convenience function for creating an NSLocalizedString? I suspect that on 5.1, that returns nil, therefore your button title is not set and the button does not get displayed.

Comment: Can you try _itemForImport = `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(itemForImportTouched)];` and see if it shows up?

Comment: @gerald william, it still doesnt show up...I've an UISegmentedControl on the same view and it shows up and works just fine. But not the button.

Comment: NVM, found the bug. I used a camera method not supported on Ipad 1, doh!

Comment: Glad it worked out. You should answer your question.